# Combining wildcard searches in MS Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to combine two search strings in one? In the example below...the commented out <[A-Z]{1,}[a-z][A-Z]{2,}> with the existing ([A-Z]{2,})

The text being searched will use upper and lower case/mix acronyms :
Sustainable Development Plan (**SDP**) 2018 to 2030 goals as they apply to the five key case and demand studies of, 1) Health 2) Education 3) Adolescents 4) Reproductive and Maternal and Newborn Health (**RMNH**) and, 5) Water Sanitation and Hygiene (**WASH**)....Ministry of Finance and Planning (**MoPF**)

I'm trying to avoid learning using RegEx!

```
With MyRange.Find

'<[A-Z]{1,}[a-z][A-Z]{2,}>

        .Text = "\([A-Z]{2,}\)"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute

While .Execute
```

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link below the question to add examples of text to be searched and what the two sets of search codes should be able to find, and what the combined set should find?

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is MS Word Find command does not support multiple Wildcard patterns in a single search with logical operators. However, you can group multiple patterns using round brackets '()' but it will find the full pattern, implementing 'AND' logic in such case. For more flexible search you should to use Regex with VBA in this case.
You can go through the [official Microsoft site for supported features of Wildcard](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/using_wildcards.html)

Comment: Incorrect.  Word offers wildcard searches which are a small subset of full blown regex but still fairly capable.  For instance I just posted some code on stack overflow for a find/replace which used "([0-9])([dhnrst]{2,2})([!0-9a-zA-Z])" as the search text.

Comment: So it would be something along the lines of ...(\([A-Z]{2,}\))(([A-Z]{1,}[a-z][A-Z]{2,}))?